# TRRS microphone not recognized on macbook pro but recognized on bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, audio, headphones, microphone

I have bought a 3.5mm TRRS mic (no headphone). When I connect it to my MacBook pro (Early 2015), however, it is only recognized as an "external headphone" and not as an input. When I bootcamp, however, it is recognized as both a headphone and a microphone, and when I set the microphone as input it works normally. Additionally, if I use a 3.5mm to lightning adapter on my iphone, it is again recognized as both a headphone and a mic and I can use the mic to record.

How do I set it up so that I can use the mic to record audio on my macOS partition?